# how can I launch textmate from Mac Finder based on a directory I see in finder?

Tags: textmate

how can I launch textmate from Mac Finder based on a directory I see in finder?

i.e. open up TextMate with the contents of that folder

e.g. I see no folder - right click - open with XXX option in Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the folder icon on TextMate's icon in your dock.

***EDIT***

Two other ways:

- You can do the same with the proxy icon situated in the Finder window's title bar. It can be useful in situations where you would loose your state when grabbing the current folder's icon.
- You can use [this handy little app](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/open-in-textmate-from-leopard-finder) to open the current folder from the Finder window's toolbar.

***ENDEDIT***